# ConcurrentModificationException: Exception in thread

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, iterator, concurrenthashmap

I'm trying to understand occurrence of `ConcurrentModificationException`in below program.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class ConcurentHashMapExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String,String> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
        myMap.put("1", "1");
        myMap.put("2", "1");
        myMap.put("3", "1");
        myMap.put("4", "1");
        myMap.put("5", "1");
        myMap.put("6", "1");
        System.out.println("ConcurrentHashMap before iterator: "+myMap);
        Iterator<String> it = myMap.keySet().iterator();

        while(it.hasNext()){
            String key = it.next();
            if(key.equals("3")) myMap.put(key+"new", "new3");
        }
        System.out.println("ConcurrentHashMap after iterator: "+myMap);

        myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        myMap.put("1", "1");
        myMap.put("2", "1");
        myMap.put("3", "1");
        myMap.put("4", "1");
        myMap.put("5", "1");
        myMap.put("6", "1");
        System.out.println("HashMap before iterator: "+myMap);
        Iterator<String> it1 = myMap.keySet().iterator();

        while(it1.hasNext()){
            String key = it1.next();
            if(key.equals("3")) myMap.put(key+"new", "new3");
        }
        System.out.println("HashMap after iterator: "+myMap);
    }

}
```

**Exception**:

```
ConcurrentHashMap before iterator: {1=1, 2=1, 3=1, 4=1, 5=1, 6=1}
ConcurrentHashMap after iterator: {1=1, 2=1, 3=1, 4=1, 5=1, 3new=new3, 6=1}
HashMap before iterator: {1=1, 2=1, 3=1, 4=1, 5=1, 6=1}
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at ConcurentHashMapExample.main(ConcurentHashMapExample.java:39)
```

My doubt is why `ConcurrentHashMap` takes care of any new entry in the map at runtime whereas `HashMap` throws `ConcurrentModificationException` ?

I'm not able to understand this reason `"Iterator on Collection objects are fail-fast i.e any modification in the structure or the number of entry in the collection object will trigger this exception thrown by iterator.`

My understanding says, `myMap` is pointing to two different objects sequentially, then how this error could happen ? Am I wrong ?

Please help to understand why its happening and reason for that. What is fail-fast as well ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

short answer: when you iterate a collection you must not change it. you can just call remove method of iterator. so below line( in hashmap case) is the reason of exception.

```
if(key.equals("3")) myMap.put(key+"new", "new3")
```

More explain:

HashMap is fail-fast

javadoc of HashMap says:

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are fail-fast

what is fail-fast? this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/a-tale-of-two-iterators) says:

> Fail fast or fail early is a software engineering concept that tries
>   to prevent complex problems from happening by stopping execution as
>   soon as something that shouldn't happen, well, happens.

ConcurrentHashMap is weakly consistent(or fail-safe)

javadoc of keyset method in ConncurentHashMap says:

> The view's iterators and spliterators are  weakly consistent

what is weakly consisten? this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/a-tale-of-two-iterators) says:

> they may proceed concurrently with other operations they will never
>   throw ConcurrentModificationException they are guaranteed to traverse
>   elements as they existed upon construction exactly once, and may (but
>   are not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.